# Primefaces Rating Method returns always null

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, primefaces, xhtml, rating

We are using Primefaces with Java EE in an Netbeans project.

What we want to do is, set a Rate Value to a variable an work with that Variable. 
But the Variable is always a Nullpointer. Can somebody help?
We Already tried Ajax and a few more things.

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>  
        <p:dataGrid var="obj" value="#{ModelUI.obj}" columns="3" rows="12" id="sers" style="text-align: center">
            <p:panel header="#{obj.name}" style="text-align:center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                    <p:rating value="#{ModelUI.rate}" stars="5">
                        <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{ModelUI.ourRateMethos()}"/>
                    </p:rating>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:dataGrid>
    </h:form>    
</h:body>
```

ModelUI:

```
@Names("ModelUI")
@Stateless
        private Integer rate;//With normal Getter and setter
        private Integer average;


            public Integer rateSchau(long id) {
                System.out.println(ratingSer);
                average = someWrapperforASeries(seriesID, ratingSer);
                return ratingSer;
            }
```

someWrapperforASeries is doing some Maths to get an average rating.

Comment: Please paste your ModelUI bean and I will be able to help you.

Comment: Okay... hope that this is enough. I tried to be as simple as possible.

Comment: OK well the first thing that stands out to me is you are using a Stateless EJB which by its definition will pull one out of the pool, set the value and return it to the pool.  You really probably want to use a Managed Bean of RequestScoped or ViewScoped.  I would simplify your test case and follow the simple samples provided by PrimeFaces here:  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/rating.xhtml

Comment: so there is no possibility to get the variable with stateless? I we change our @Stateless to an other annotation nothing will work and we don´t have enough time left to rewrite the whole program.

Comment: Well without more information or more examples I can't help you.  The code from the showcase works fine and the Rating object works fine.  So it has something to do with the way you are using it and the @Stateless bean feels like its a mess to me.  You are combining UI logic with Persistence logic.

Comment: okay thanks for your help. ^^